# Is it really possible to find primary decomposition of given ideal without using Macaulay2?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm solving some exercises from my class notes of Commutative Algebra. Here is one exercise on which I'm stuck:

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $p=(x^4-yz,y^2-xz,z^2-x^3y) \subset k[x,y,z]$ be an ideal. Find the primary decomposition of $p^2$.

First I noted that $p$ is prime ideal because it's kernel of the map $\phi:k[x,y,z] \to k[t]$ defined by $x \to t^3,y \to t^5,z \to t^7$. Clearly $p^2$ will have many generators. Also as rad$(p^2)=p$, so $p^2$ is not a radical ideal. (Therefore I think it's not easy to decompose $p^2$.) So I was wondering is there really a "good" way to find primary decomposition of $p^2$. I don't really see any "good" way to find primary decomposition of $p^2$ by hand. Any idea/suggestion?

**Added:** As a hint I was told by my Prof. that the $p$-primary component of $p^2$ will be $p^{(2)}$. But still I'm unable to complete this.

**Edit:**  As $p^{(2)}$ is the $p$-primary component of $p^2$ and $$f=x^7-3x^3yz+x^2y^3+z^2 = x^{-1}(x^8+y^2z^2-2x^4yz)- x^{-1}(y^2z^2-x^3y^3-xz^3+x^4yz)$$ hence $f \in p^{(2)}$. Also clearly $p^2 \subseteq p^{(2)}$, hence $(p^2,f) \subseteq p^{(2)}$. But Macaulay2 says that $(p^2,f)$ is the $p$-primary component. Does anyone have any idea why $p^{(2)} \subseteq (p^2,f)$ ?

Comment: Well, sometimes this can be an impossible mission.

Comment: @user26857.Actually this is an exercise in my class notes.Thats why I was hoping for an answer.

Comment: Well, a primary decomposition of $p^2$ is just a description of $p^2$ into an intersection of **primary** ideals. But $p^2$ is itself primary, since $\sqrt{p^2}=p$.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer Why does this imply $p^2$ is primary? (We only know that $p$ is prime ideal)

Comment: @Arpit Sorry, I was too quick - I recalled something wrongly.

Comment: Well, I think the hint is not so helpful: Macaulay2 shows that $p^2$ has also an embedded prime, that is, $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @user26857 Correct,Prof  also told me answer is $p^2= J \cap K$ where $J=(p^2+f)$ and $K=(z,y^4,x^3y^3,x^4y^2,x^7y,x^8)$ where Ass($R/J$)=$p$ and $Ass(R/K)=(x,y,z)$. where $f=x^7+x^2y^3-3x^3yz+z^3 $ and $f \in p^{(2)}$

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what Macaulay2 gives, and I have some feelings that this is the way he/she found it.