# Localization of $k[[x,y,z]]$ at a prime ideal.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am solving an exercise in commutative algebra in which I need localization of a power series ring at prime ideal.

> Let $R=k[[x,y,z]]$, $p=(x^4-yz,y^2-xz,z^2-x^3y)$ be a prime ideal of $R$. Is there a "nice" description of the ring $R_p$? (Here I'm assuming that $k$ is algebraically closed.)

Of course, if we localize at a prime ideal $p$ of a ring $R$,then the multiplicative set that gets inverted is $S=R-p$. So everything outside $p$ is invertible in $R-p$ hence $R_p$ is a local ring. But I doubt that there is a nice description for $R_p$. Any hints/ideas?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505022/is-it-really-possible-to-find-primary-decomposition-of-given-ideal-without-using